# git accept edited hunk but ignores it afterwards

Tags: git

so git has some issues detecting a proper logical consistancy like a method with comment header. And to have a clean nice commit i edit the hunk myself. Which is easy in that case because it is just adding a - at the beginning and removing it at the bottom.

A little Excample what i mean:

ORIGINAL:

```
class pseudo {

    /**
     * test
     */
    public foo() {
       test1();
    }

    /**
     * test1
     */
    public foo1() {
        test1();
    }

    /**
     * test2
     */
    public foo2() {
        test1();
    }

    /**
     * testX
     */
    public fooX() {
        test1();
    }
}
```

NOW REMOVE A METHOD (Method foo2)

```
class pseudo {

    /**
     * test
     */
    public foo() {
       test1();
    }

    /**
     * test1
     */
    public foo1() {
        test1();
    }

    /**
     * testX
     */
    public fooX() {
        test1();
    }
}
```

GIT NOW SHOWS THE FOLLOWING

```
-13,xy - +13,xy
    public foo1() {
        test1();
    }

    /**
-    * test2
-   */
-   public foo2() {
-       test1();
-   }
-
-   /**
    * testX
```

I would add a - a line above * test2 and remove it at the end which would make a clean and proper hunk.

Git accepts it without issues but at the end the old hunk is staged.

A friend of mine thinks the issue is that for git it doesn't matter. My hunk and the previous is the 'same' but after all when i edit a hunk, it shouldn't play around with it.

How can i fix this?

Comment: `git` does not care at all about the semantic structure of the contents of the files - in order to do so it would have to learn a lot about every possible file type out there. It only cares about generating a patch that will turn file A into file B, whether or not it looks aesthetically pleasing to a human or adheres to some arbitrary semantic structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git tracks the *state* of files, not the differences.  An output like the one you posted is generated on-the-fly by the tools, just like `diff -u` does.  What is relevant to git is how the file looks when you stage it, not how you got there.  So yes, what you did is basically a no-op to git.

> How can i fix this?

You could try to adjust the way git shows a diff to you, but I don't think it's worth the trouble.